# Testing in app purchase on iOS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to add an in-app purchase mechanishm to my application. As I understand from Apple documents, I have to send my binary before I add some in-app purchasing code.

I'm not sure about something. If I send my binary with the 1.0 version, will I able to publish my application with the 1.0 version in future? Because I will add some in-app purchase after my app is reviewed and accepted by Apple and send it (or update it) again.

How this mechanishm works in Apple? How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the binary and then Apple will hopefully will approve you application.

When Apple have approved your application you can either choose to release it to app-store or wait and add more code.

Comment: So is that possible to decide which binary will be published as 1.0 version?

Comment: You can only submit one binary at a time and the one you submit will be the one published. If you want to submit another binary, you will have to reject the current one, or replace it by submitting an update

Answer (score 0):

You are confused, you need to add the in-app purchase code with your 1.0 binary. Also submit any existing in-app purchases to be reviewed along with your binary.

If you need to add more in-app purchases in the future, you can either submit a new binary with the new in-app purchases. Or, if you don't need code changes to add new IAPs, you can simply create them on itunes connect and submit them for review without updating the binary.

In conclusion, there is NO version of the binary that needs to be submittied WITHOUT the IAP-related code.